# Making single digit numbers between 1 and 9 into double digits, inside CSV file

Tags: text-processing, csv-simple

I have a CSV file with thousands of lines like these

```
1664;4;5;35;37;43;5;6
1663;21;23;32;40;49;8;11
1662;16;17;34;35;44;5;10
1661;2;9;23;32;40;6;7
1660;23;25;30;44;47;9;12
1659;3;5;9;32;43;6;10
1658;4;6;10;13;34;3;5
1657;8;9;33;35;40;3;6
1656;15;20;31;44;48;1;3
1655;25;27;35;40;45;7;11
1654;7;32;33;34;38;6;9
1653;5;7;11;27;37;6;12
1652;7;31;33;35;36;7;10
1651;4;12;34;35;45;1;9
1650;5;8;29;35;48;5;6
1649;2;11;28;42;48;4;9
1648;2;11;12;19;38;4;8
```

You can see that the numbers between 1 and 9 are single digit.

How can I use `sed` or something to covert these number into double digit, by preceding a zero to them, such as

```
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09
```

instead of

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: something that may (or may not) be important: If you then intend to manipulate some of those numbers with a shell (for ex: bash) : it may interpret numbers "08" or "09" as an invalid octal number, in some contexts...

Comment: Hey look, an XY problem.

Comment: What about single digit `0`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a solution using `awk`:

```shell
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=sprintf("%02d",$i)} 1' file.csv
```

This will first set the input and output field separator to `;`. It will then iterate over all fields and normalize the field width to at least two digits with left zero-padding by using `sprintf()` (which *effectively* won't change the field content if it is already a two-digit number).

The seemingly stray `1` outside of the action blocks instructs `awk` to print the current line including all changes.

Note that `awk` will not by default modify the file, but only print to `stdout`, so you will either

- have to redirect output to a temporary file and rename, as in

  ```shell
  awk ' ... ' file.csv > output.csv && mv output.csv file.csv
  ```
- or use an `awk` version that supports the `-i inplace` extension:

  ```shell
  awk -i inplace ' ... ' file.csv
  ```

Also note that this particular case is tailored to your example input which only comprises single- or double-digit numbers. For the more general case of padding to `n` digits, you would use

```shell
awk -v n=3 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=sprintf("%0*d",n,$i)} 1' file.csv
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `sed` to pick out a "word" that's a single digit, and prefix it with zero:

```
sed -E 's/\<([0-9])\>/0\1/g' {file}
```

Overall:

- The `-E` flag ensures that `sed` will use an Extended Regular Expression (ERE) rather than a standard/ordinary Regular Expression.
- `s/ …pattern… / …replacement… /g` defines a substitution that applies an ERE match on `…pattern…` and corresponding replacement with `…replacement…`. Because of the `g` ("global") flag the match/replace is applied as many times as possible for a line.
- There is no line selection so implicitly it applies this rule to every line in the input.

In the ERE match pattern:

- `\<` and `\>` represent a word boundary
- `(` and `)` identify a grouped expression that can be reused later
- `[0-9]` is any single digit

In the ERE substitution:

- `0` is a literal `0` character
- `\1` interpolates the text captured by the first grouped expression, i.e. an instance of a single digit

Output:

```
1664;04;05;35;37;43;05;06
1663;21;23;32;40;49;08;11
1662;16;17;34;35;44;05;10
1661;02;09;23;32;40;06;07
1660;23;25;30;44;47;09;12
1659;03;05;09;32;43;06;10
1658;04;06;10;13;34;03;05
1657;08;09;33;35;40;03;06
1656;15;20;31;44;48;01;03
1655;25;27;35;40;45;07;11
1654;07;32;33;34;38;06;09
1653;05;07;11;27;37;06;12
1652;07;31;33;35;36;07;10
1651;04;12;34;35;45;01;09
1650;05;08;29;35;48;05;06
1649;02;11;28;42;48;04;09
1648;02;11;12;19;38;04;08
```

In this case it doesn't matter whether the file really is CSV (fields separated by comma, "`,`"), or if it has fields separated by semicolon ("`;`"), or even fields separated by whitespace.

If your `sed` supports `-i` you can edit the file "in place", but note that in common with most other utilities the "in place" effect is actually implemented behind the scenes as "write to a temporary file, and then replace the original file with that temporary one":

```
sed -E 's/\<([0-9])\>/0\1/g' file >file.$$.tmp &&
    mv -f file.$$.tmp file
rm -f file.$$.tmp
```

Comment: Note that `\<` / `\>` (from ex/vi) are not standard. Some common alternatives (not standard either) are `\b` (from perl) or `[[:<:]]`/`[[:>]]` (found on some BSDs). `-E` will be standard in the next  revision of the POSIX standard and is already available in many `sed` implementations. What `[0-9]` matches is unspecified outside the POSIX locale.

Comment: You don't need the `(...)` capture groups, you can just use `&` in the replacement to refer to the whole match.

Answer (score 5):

Given your input sample, it looks like

```
perl -pi -e 's/\b\d\b/0$&/g' file.csv
```

Should do it.

That prepends a `0` to all digits that are both preceded and followed by a word `b`oundary. Replace `\d` with `[1-9]` if you want `0` to be left alone as the wording of your question suggests.

The same with the GNU implementation of `sed`

```
sed -i 's/\b[[:digit:]]\b/0&/g' file.csv
```

With recent versions of `mlr` (miller), you can also do:

```
mlr --csv -N --fs ';' put '$* = fmtifnum($*, "%02d")'
```

To format all numeric fields as integers 0-padded to a length of 2.

That will leave numbers in non-numeric fields (like in `"foo 1 and 2";x-2`) untouched, but note that it will also reformat non-integer numbers (`1e0`, `10e-1`, `1.123`, `0x1` would all be changed to `01` for instance).

To only pad the fields that consist of only one decimal digit (quoted or not):

```
mlr --csv -N --fs ';' put 'for (k in $*) {$[k] = sub(string($[k]),"^\d$","0\0")}'
```

Answer (score 5):

Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/6.9.0/) with type inference (`-A`) and outputing integer values with zero padding and minimum field width of 2:

```
mlr -A --nidx --fs ';' --ofmt '%02d' cat file
```

Note that based on your input sample I've assumed the data is actually index-numbered rather than CSV.

Comment: The only thing needing to change if you want Miller to read it as CSV is to swap `--nidx` for `--cvs -N`.  It might matter if the input uses CSV quoting rules, but it doesn't in this simple example case.

Comment: @Kusalananda when I tried that with mlr 6.0.0 it seems to insist on quoting every field in the output - is there an additional option I'm missing (like the opposite of `--quote-all`)?

Comment: I fail to find any mention of this in the GitHub issues or the release documents, but I can confirm that release 6.0.0 did quote the fields as you described in your comment.  Release 6.1.0 and later ones (6.9.0 is soon out) do not.

Answer (score 3):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -MText::CSV -e 'my @a = csv(in => $*IN, sep => ";", strict => True);        \
                        @a = @a>>.map( {sprintf "%.2d", $_ } );    \
                        csv(in => @a, out => $*OUT, sep => ";");'  file
```

The code above uses Raku's `Text::CSV` module. In the first statement the CSV file is read-in, setting the `sep` parameter to accept `;` semicolons as column separators. In the second statement the `sprintf` directive `"%.2d"` sets each column to a minimum width of 2, zero-padded. In the output `;` semicolons are restored as column separators, otherwise the default will be used (comma).

The above answer holds for CSV files with every column being integer. So far *unsigned* integers are `NYI` (not-yet-implemented). It might be preferable to use the ***string*** form of `sprintf`, taking care to add `0` to the formatting code, which directs padding with zeros insted of blank spaces. Alternate second statement below:

`@a = @a>>.map( {sprintf "%02s", $_ } );`

Sample Input:

```
1664;4;5;35;37;43;5;6
1663;21;23;32;40;49;8;11
1662;16;17;34;35;44;5;10
1661;2;9;23;32;40;6;7
1660;23;25;30;44;47;9;12
1659;3;5;9;32;43;6;10
1658;4;6;10;13;34;3;5
1657;8;9;33;35;40;3;6
1656;15;20;31;44;48;1;3
1655;25;27;35;40;45;7;11
1654;7;32;33;34;38;6;9
1653;5;7;11;27;37;6;12
1652;7;31;33;35;36;7;10
1651;4;12;34;35;45;1;9
1650;5;8;29;35;48;5;6
1649;2;11;28;42;48;4;9
1648;2;11;12;19;38;4;8
```

Sample Output (either example above):

```
1664;04;05;35;37;43;05;06
1663;21;23;32;40;49;08;11
1662;16;17;34;35;44;05;10
1661;02;09;23;32;40;06;07
1660;23;25;30;44;47;09;12
1659;03;05;09;32;43;06;10
1658;04;06;10;13;34;03;05
1657;08;09;33;35;40;03;06
1656;15;20;31;44;48;01;03
1655;25;27;35;40;45;07;11
1654;07;32;33;34;38;06;09
1653;05;07;11;27;37;06;12
1652;07;31;33;35;36;07;10
1651;04;12;34;35;45;01;09
1650;05;08;29;35;48;05;06
1649;02;11;28;42;48;04;09
1648;02;11;12;19;38;04;08
```

Input/Output: You can redirect output to a new file taking the excellent code from either @AdminBee or @roiama (or both). If you want to direct Input/Output from *within-the-code* itself, the `$*IN` and `$*OUT` dynamic values can be replaced by PATHs (see second URL below for details).

https://docs.raku.org/routine/sprintf
https://github.com/Tux/CSV
https://raku.org

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this is overkill for a file with only digits and semicolons, but for a more complex CSV file with other characters, quoting, etc. this is the approach needed.

Comment: @reinierpost digits and semicolons, agreed. But it wasn't clear from the OP's question if that will be true in all cases, specifically whether-or-not decimal digits and/or negative numbers will be present in the input CSV files.

Comment: Indeed. Multiple answers for the same question is a useful feature.

Answer (score 0):

Super crude.
Super slow.
May be useful.

Using any text editor -
replace all occurrences of ",1," with ",01," etc

Single digits at the end of line need to eg
replace all occurrences of ",3[EOL identifier]" with ",03[EOL identifier]"

Comment: Poor answer! One could use `:%s/;\([0-9]\;/;0\1;/g` in `vi` to fix *all* with *one* command!

Comment: @U.Windl This will ignore the last "column" in the file. See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/755729/11417) for a better pattern.

Comment: OK, one would need a second command `:%s/;\([0-9]$/;0\1/` then. I'm not aware what `\<` does in `sed` as the original `sed` does not know that.

Comment: @U.Windl  By your criteria several of the other answers are "poor answers" because they use more than one line of code.  And [tm], using vi may be deemed to make it a poor answer by Richard Stallman, and many Emacs users :-). || If I was doing this personally I'd perhaps open it with Excel, and write  a 'formula' that produced a new corrected array that then exported as a CSV. Also 'crude'. Has the merit of producing an on screen live record of input and output what can be checked for any "gotchas" (such as eg yours had - that happens - beeing able to check it "live" is useful. )

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I was specifically referring to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/755825/320598) answer as "poor", because it is quite unspecific *how* to actually do it. Specifically it does not even mention regular expressions. - That's what I wanted to point out in my comment(s). - Also I did not ask the OP *why* such change is needed at all: For humans to parse the CSV more easily? ;-)

Comment: @U.Windl  Fair enough **IF** you interpret " ... How can I use sed or something ... " as meaning MUST use regular expressions. I was not specific as I said ANY text editor. I had in mind find and replace. As noted, very crude.
Also works well enough if other solutions are not viable for some (strange :-) ) reason.

Comment: @U.Windl If a user is not familiar with regular expressions, and is looking for a one-time solution, doing a series of repeated search/replace will be dramatically faster than doing the research needed to learn how to construct a regex, test it, and apply it.

Comment: @barbecue You may be right: About 32 years ago a company where I had worked for a short time had asked a student to do a similar task for a large file, and the estimated time to do it was one week (it was a bit more complex than this). At that time I had my own version of MicroEmacs running on MS-DOS, and it took me about 10 minutes to find the solution and the job was done in 5 minutes then. Sometimes knowing the tools you have or thinking before starting to work may be beneficial.

Comment: If you intend on substituting "`,1,`" with "`,01,`" in a text-editor, that won't address single-digits in both the first and last columns. You'll need a text-editor that can do search/replace using  "begins-with" and "ends-with" criteria, adjusting the search pattern accordingly.

Comment: @jubilatious1 I missed th leading digit case. The final digit case is covered by my "... [EOL identifier". |